# Legend won't properly place data and labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have data from two different dataframes.

```
ice_data_dates

Date    2011    2012    2013    2014    2015    2016    2017    2018    2019    2020    max_value   min_value
Date                                                
01 Jan  12.896  13.353  12.959  13.011  13.073  12.721  12.643  12.484  12.876  13.102  13.353  12.484
02 Jan  12.915  13.421  12.961  13.103  13.125  12.806  12.644  12.600  12.956  13.075  13.421  12.600
03 Jan  12.926  13.379  13.012  13.116  13.112  12.790  12.713  12.634  12.959  13.176  13.379  12.634
04 Jan  13.051  13.414  13.045  13.219  13.051  12.829  12.954  12.724  13.047  13.187  13.414  12.724
05 Jan  13.176  13.417  13.065  13.148  13.115  12.874  12.956  12.834  13.098  13.123  13.417  12.834

ice_data_climo

    DOY AverageExtent   StdDeviation    10th    25th    50th    75th    90th
0   1   13.778  0.407   13.183  13.479  13.823  14.095  14.257
1   2   13.842  0.434   13.201  13.538  13.886  14.164  14.321
2   3   13.891  0.443   13.264  13.502  13.884  14.283  14.369
3   4   13.930  0.443   13.284  13.590  13.925  14.288  14.417
4   5   13.978  0.437   13.349  13.617  14.036  14.304  14.470
```

I make a line plot below.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ice_data_dates.plot(figsize=(20,12), lw=3, fontsize=16, ax=ax, grid=True)
for line in ax.get_lines():
    if line._label == '2020':
        line.set_linewidth(6)
        line.set_color('k')

legend=['2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '1981-2010 Average', 'Interquartile Range', 'Interdecile Range']
plt.text(0.80, 0.97, "Sea Ice Extent for" + " " +str(plot_date)+ "=%f $10^6$ km" %ice_today, fontsize=16, horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
plt.text(0.80, 0.94, "Min Sea Ice Extent for" + " " +str(plot_date)+ "=%f $10^6$ km" %min_today, fontsize=16, horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
plt.text(0.80, 0.91, "Max Sea Ice Extent for" + " " +str(plot_date)+ "=%f $10^6$ km" %max_today, fontsize=16, horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', transform=ax.transAxes)

plt.plot(ice_climo['DOY'], ice_climo['AverageExtent'], c='k', lw=3, linestyle='--')

plt.fill_between(ice_climo['DOY'],ice_climo['AverageExtent'],ice_climo['25th'], color='dimgray', alpha=0.7)
plt.fill_between(ice_climo['DOY'],ice_climo['AverageExtent'],ice_climo['10th'], color='lightgray', alpha=0.5)
plt.fill_between(ice_climo['DOY'],ice_climo['AverageExtent'],ice_climo['75th'], color='dimgray', alpha=0.7)
plt.fill_between(ice_climo['DOY'],ice_climo['AverageExtent'],ice_climo['90th'], color='lightgray', alpha=0.5)


plt.title('Arctic Sea Ice Extent for the Latest 10 Years', fontsize=22, weight='bold' )    
ax.set_xlabel("Date", weight='bold', fontsize=16)
ax.set_ylabel("Sea Ice Extent ($10^6$ km)", weight='bold', fontsize=16)
ax.legend(legend, loc='lower left', fontsize=20)
plt.axvline(x=plot_day, c='k', linestyle='--')
```

That produces this figure.

[image]

But if you notice, the legend is messed up for some reason. The 1981-2010 average should be a dashed black line and the interquartile/interdecile averages should be differing shades of gray. What exactly am I messing up here with the legend?

Comment: Maybe you could also add labels for the 'max_value' and 'min_value' columns? Now they are drawn but you don't list them in the `legend` list.

Comment: How does that change anything? I am not plotting the max and min, only displaying them as text in the top right hand corner.

Comment: Well, they are plotted as part of `ice_data_dates.plot(...)`. You could remove them if you don't want them as part of the line plots.

Comment: Ah good catch. Thank you